# Angular table sortable and exclude records with date before yesterday

Tags: angular, html-table

I have a firebase database where I store some details of a reservation which I want to show on my angular 5 website. I get the reservations like this:

```
this.reservations = this.db.list('/reservations').valueChanges();
```

the reservations field is an `Observable<any[]>;` which I put in a table.

```
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
  <th scope="col">Email</th>
  <th scope="col">Name</th>
  <th scope="col">From</th>
  <th scope="col">To</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngFor="let reservation of reservations| async">
<tr>
  <td>{{reservation.email}}</td>
  <td>{{reservation.firstName}} {{reservatie.lastName}}</td>
  <td>{{showAsDate(reservation.dateFrom)}}</td>
  <td>{{showAsDate(reservation.dateTo)}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Which looks like this
[image: screenshot]
My question is how do I make the table colomns sortable on click do I have to do it in the code myself or is there a another way?
Next question; I want to exclude all records that are before yesterday, do I loop the records and fill new List with the records that are after yesterday or is there an "Angular" way to do it? By that I mean with ngFor or (action) in html.

Comment: Create a Pipe for sorting your entries. Create a pipe that filters out old records

Comment: @John, NOT use a pipe for sorting entries. Sort the array by code

Comment: Ah, yes. Otherwise the sorting will happen on each change detection.

Comment: Oh I could use a pipe to format a string 02092018 to a date too? Now I wrote `showAsDate(date:string)` which substrings the day, month, year out of there and then I convert them to numbers Number.parseInt and use the constructor of Date to make it a Date and use the dateString with locale to make it readible for where I live but for the month I have to substract by one for some reason months start at 0.